# Some websites hosted on my server cant be reached from some places

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, nameserver

I have a bloblem that is causing me headaches to solve. I have a webserver at 100tb.com, running CentOS.

I also have these nameservers setted up:

**67.213.220.170    ns1.maisturismo.net

67.213.220.171  ns2.maisturismo.net**

My domain is at Godaddy.
I added two Host Summary pointig to the nameserver ips... NS1 to the first IP, and NS2 to the second...

Than I changed the nameservers of maisturismo.net to ns1.maisturismo.net and ns2.maisturismo.net

**http://img20.imageshack.us/i/dnswm.jpg/**

Bellow the image showing my dns records to maisturismo.net

**http://img137.imageshack.us/i/nameservers.jpg/**

Its strange... Everythink looks fine, but the webiste is not reachable from [zend2.com][1] proxy, and from some other places, like a friend's house, that dont use the same web provider that I use.

I have another nameserver setted up on my server, that have the same problem, All websites that use it cant be reached from zend2.com and from my friends house, except a ".com.br"(Brazillian Domain).

Do you have same idea about, what is causing this? I really cant imagine what is the problem...

Thanks.

[1]: http:// zend2.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a bad glue record for ns2.maisturismo.net -- it thinks it's on 67.213.220.17, not 67.213.220.171.

```
dig @b.gtld-servers.net ns2.maisturismo.net

; <<>> DiG 9.6.0-APPLE-P2 <<>> @b.gtld-servers.net ns2.maisturismo.net
; (2 servers found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 26766
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 2
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ns2.maisturismo.net.       IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
maisturismo.net.    172800  IN  NS  ns1.maisturismo.net.
maisturismo.net.    172800  IN  NS  ns2.maisturismo.net.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.maisturismo.net.    172800  IN  A   67.213.220.170
ns2.maisturismo.net.    172800  IN  A   67.213.220.17

;; Query time: 487 msec
;; SERVER: 192.33.14.30#53(192.33.14.30)
;; WHEN: Sat Jan  8 12:20:39 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 101
```

You need to fix that with GoDaddy.

Comment: Thank you. How did you check this? What command to use to report these data? Ns2 was really wrong... The other nameservers that I'm also having problems, are ns1.socialdub.com and ns2.socialdub.com. They dont look to have something wrong.

Comment: I used the dig command, as shown in the top line of the quoted bit of my response.

The DNS for the socialdub.com domain looks OK, as far as I can tell, so I'm not sure what the problem is there.